# Disable button for every user and clickable button only for admin

Tags: java, android, button, reset

I have a reset button which only admin can click and for users it wil be disabled always meaning only admin can reset counts. How to do it?

````
           @Override
           public void onClick(View arg0) {

               count10counter=0;
               tvcount10.setText ( String.valueOf ( count10counter ) );

           }
       } );```
````

Comment: how did you implement  the recognization   of admin or user login in your app ?? do you have any unique  token number for admin??

Comment: @NiajMahmud i can implement user log but when user is logged in reset button should be invisible for them

Answer (score 0):

At your activity, get the button by its id and set its visibility to invisible. Paste this code where you implement user log:

```
Button btn = findViewById (R.id.reset_button); // reset_button is the view id taken from the xml file
btn.setVisibility (View.GONE);
```